# Cannot get referrer properties using react-native-install-referrer

Tags: react-native, firebase-dynamic-links, referrals

I am trying to implement a referral system in a React Native Android app, using the [react-native-install-referrer package](https://openbase.com/js/react-native-install-referrer), with the following code:

```js
import RNInstallReferrer from 'react-native-install-referrer';

const handleReferrer = async () =>
    try {
        const referrer = await RNInstallReferrer.getReferrer();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)}
    }
}
```

It fails with this error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getReferrer') while
> using react-native-install-referrer

What I am I doing wrong?